# Python Pandas:How to find rows in which value of one column is subset of values in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
  Possible_Values                          Default_Value 
  Yes||No                                  Yes
  Sport||Adventure||tourer                 Cruiser
  Low End||Mid Range||Top End              None
```

above is my dataframe, for which I want to extract rows, where value in column 'Default_Value' is not in values in column 'Possible_Value'. Please note that values in 'Possible_Values' columns are pipe || separated. 
I am using Pandas==0.20.3.

Comment: What is the output

Comment: Completely unclear question

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can check if one is present in other:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x : x['Default_Value'] in x['Possible_Values'],1)
ndf = df[mask]
```

```
 Possible_Values Default_Value    
0         Yes||No           Yes
```

If you want the opposite of this then `ndf = df[~mask]`

```
                Possible_Values Default_Value
1     Sport||Adventure||tourer       Cruiser
2  Low End||Mid Range||Top End          None
```

Comment: A big Thanks, Bharath. Although this didn't work directly but it gave me right direction for how to do it.

Comment: Well the question is bit unclear. If you provide the expected output I could help better

Comment: Agreed. Thanks again.